# Error when assinging a range value to a variable indicates that it is not set (although it is not an object)

Tags: vba

I've been trying to implement the following macro to ease the formatting of an excel file but when launched it indicates an error 91 as an object not being set.
My problem here is that I'm not manipulating an object (at least not on the line the debugger flags me the error) but modifying a variable (double) to the value of a found cell.

Code:

```
Dim id_UO As Double
Dim id_UO_Up As Double
id_UO = Source.Cells(x,1).Value
id_UO_Up = Source.Cells(x,8).Value

hierarchie.Add id_UO

Dim cell As Range
Columns("A:A").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find( _
What:=id_UO_Up, _
After:=ActiveCell, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)

id_UO = cell.Value 'error happens here'
cell = cell.Resize(cell.row,7)
id_UO_Up = cell.Value
```

The error happens when assigning the cell.Value to id_UO.

Comment: Are you sure Find was successful? If it wasn't then cell would be Nothing, and that would cause the error you describe.

Comment: Ah shoot... you are right, I assumed the file given was complete, I'll add a catch to that and see if that fixes it. I've been banging my head on the keyboard but should have thought about it earlier, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Norie answered my question, I assumed the data always had a match in the first column for the id_UO_Up value but it didn't a simple

```
If not cell is Nothing
```

check let me bypass it and treat outlying unfound values.
Thanks again for the reply @norie